# C# Message box without default button

Tags: c#, button, default, messagebox

This seems too simple to not have an answer readily available, but is it possible to have a MessageBox in a C# WinForms application with Yes and No buttons, but that does not set either as the "default" button? I know there's the MessageBoxDefaultButton property that you can set, but I can't seem to set it to nothing. Is this really not possible?

Comment: This is how `MessageBox` works and the way how most users expect it to works when they see it. Question is why you don't like its behavior?

Comment: The reason it's not desired in this case is that "Yes" or "No" are intended to be equally viable answers in this case, and making one of them the default or to appear encouraged over the other is not desired behavior. Personally, I think one of the options SHOULD be favored, and as such, the existing behavior is totally fine, but that's not my call in this case.

Comment: Good point, but from usability point of view pressing `Enter` is quicker than setting focus to `Yes` and pressing enter, right? As a user you will be confused to see usual `MessageBox` which doesn't react on `Enter` key. This is what default button property does. You have to choose the one which is better. E.g. in case of "Do you want to delete file" you may want to set `No` as default, so that user can't delete file accidentally by clicking Enter twice: on `Delete` button and in confirmation dialog. This is the whole point. If this is not a case - leave `Yes` as default button.

Comment: @Habib I reopened this question (actually, I didn't know I had the magic hammer to do that) since this question isn't about a message box with no buttons, but a message box with no default button highlighted.

Comment: @LarsTech, you did the right thing, before the edit the question had "but is it possible to have a MessageBox in a C# WinForms application that does not have a default button? "

Comment: So what's the behaviour without explicitly setting a `MessageBoxDefaultButton`. Is it that the first button is highlighted?someone pressing

Comment: You could just catch and discard enter key presses, if you want your user to have to use the mouse. I would point out that the use case "open messagebox, navigate using arrow keys, press enter" would be broken by this. But seeing no default, if possible, may very well break the use of arrows anyway. In case it's not obvious, subverting the user's expectation by disabling (breaking) things in your UI is a bad idea.

Comment: So the way I see it, there are two choices - make a custom form for this, or convince the business to favor one answer over the other, which was my preferred choice to begin with. Breaking UI conventions is not desirable. And not setting MessageBoxDefaultButton is what's in there now - which defaults it to the first box, in this case, the "Yes" button.

Comment: There is also the goofy third choice: Have Yes-No-Cancel and set the Button3 as the default (the Cancel button).  And yes, I said it was goofy.

Comment: I would remind them that this isn't how you reckon it should be, but is in fact how Microsoft decided windows should be when they made the Win32 Model Dialog Box.

Comment: LarsTech - I'd actually considered that option, but rejected it quickly in this case, because what we have then is a default button that nobody would actually want to ever click. Also, it would make for an awkward user experience in this case. Oddly enough, one of the decision makers actually liked that idea, and it took a group effort to convince him it wasn't a good idea.